# Is it possible to select a face in the UV editor and find it in the 3D View?

Tags: uv

I have a mesh which i have Smart UV projected , and i have many loose UV faces . I would like to know if i am able to select a face in the UV/Image editor , And make it select the face on the 3D mesh. Is this possible?

I cannot select every face on my 3D mesh to find the correct face in the UV , That is very time consuming and confusing. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

In the header of the UV editor window there's a button named *Keep UV and edit mode mesh selection in sync*, an icon with an arrow pointing to a cube mesh.

That solved your problem.
Consider that also in the UV window you can choose if to work with vertices, edges or faces.

Note that if this button is selected, you can't edit the UV islands.

UV Sync Selection button:

[image]